# Is there a way to change the log format of GLOG?

Tags: glog

I am working with GLOG in one of our components.
My company enforce a specific log format.

Is there a way to change the GLOG log format?
(couldn't find any API for that)

Comment: i also ran into this problem, and the way I found to solve it is to modify the source code , function **LogMessage::Init** in **logging.cc** and change the format to whatever you want. perhaps there's no api provided officially to do so.

Comment: Doesn't look like the format is customizable at this time: https://github.com/google/glog/issues/229